# Pygame - Horizontal Collision

Tags: pygame, collision-detection, collision, horizontal-scrolling

I am having trouble with my player having horizontal collision. I have commented out the code that I have tried and have looked at tutorials from **DaFluffyPotato** and **KidsCanCode** but I either the character would hardly move or he would fall infinitely.

```
    def collide(self):
        self.player.rect.x = self.player.pos.x

        for each in self.map.blocks:
            if self.player.rect.colliderect(each):
                # Landing Collision
                if self.player.vel.y > 0:
                    if self.player.pos.y < each.bottom:
                        self.player.pos.y = each.top + 1
                        self.player.vel.y = 0

                
                # if self.player.rect.x < 0:
                #     self.player.rect.right = each.left
                #     self.player.vel.x = 0
                # # # self.player.rect.top = each.bottom
                # elif self.player.rect.x > 0:
                #     self.player.rect.right = each.left
                #     self.player.vel.x = 0


                # Jump
                self.player.able_jump = True
                jump = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if jump[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    self.player.vel.y = -self.settings.jump_height

            else:
                self.player.able_jump = False
```

**Player Movement Code**

```
    def update(self):
    """Controls the player's position."""
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)


    moving = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if moving[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.acc.x = -self.settings.acceleration
    if moving[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.acc.x = self.settings.acceleration
    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * self.settings.friction
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
     
    if self.pos.x > self.settings.screen_width:
        self.pos.x = 0
    if self.pos.x < 0:
        self.pos.x = self.settings.screen_width
    
    if self.pos.y > (self.settings.screen_height + 400):
        self.pos.y = 0
        
    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos      

    self.able_jump = False
```

**Map Code**(I know there is a Class Indention)

```
import csv
import pygame

from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Map(Sprite):

def __init__(self, game):
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = game.screen
    self.settings = game.settings
    mapname = 'practice\map.csv'
    infinitemapname = 'practice\infinitemap.csv'

    self.full_map = []
    with open(mapname) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            self.full_map.append(list(row))
    
    self.dirt_block = pygame.image.load('block.png')
    


def draw(self):
    """This method draws the map."""
    self.blocks = []
    for y, line in enumerate(self.full_map):
        for x, c in enumerate(line):
            if c == "0":
                center = ((x*10)+4, (y*10)+4)
                self.blocks.append(self.dirt_block.get_rect(center=center))
                self.screen.blit(self.dirt_block, (x * 10-self.settings.scroll[0], y * 10-self.settings.scroll[1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem one day. I think you sould use `collidelistall(retc_list)` instead `colliderect(rect)`.
It will check if any rect in the list is touching the player rect.
So i think you should use this:

```py
if self.player.rect.collidelistall(self.map.blocks):
```